# Open specific fragment destination in Navigation graph when click on push notification & graph is in other than launcher activity

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-push-notification

I want to open a specific fragment in navigation component graph when user click on a push notification.
But I've more than one navigation graphs. The destination fragment I want to navigate is not in the graph of  launcher activity.

```
val pendingIntent = NavDeepLinkBuilder(this)
            .setGraph(R.navigation.nav_home)
            .setDestination(R.id.detailsFragment)
            .setArguments(args)
            .createPendingIntent()

        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this,
            getChannelIDForOnGoingNotification(this)
        ).setContentTitle(remoteMessage?.data?.get("title"))
            .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
            .setColor(getNotificationColor())
            .setContentText(remoteMessage?.data?.get("body"))
            .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setStyle(bigText)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build())
```

I'm using the above code to make deep linking using `NavDeepLinkBuilder`. But `R.navigation.nav_home` is not in the launcher activity. When I click on notification it simply open the launcher activity, but don't open the target activity & fragment.

How could I open the target activity that has the graph which has my target fragment using Android Navigation component

Answer (score 4):

You must add

```
.setComponentName(MainActivity::class.java)
```

your code should look like this:

```
    val pendingIntent = NavDeepLinkBuilder(this)
        .setComponentName(MainActivity::class.java) // your destination activity
        .setGraph(R.navigation.nav_home)
        .setDestination(R.id.detailsFragment)
        .setArguments(args)
        .createPendingIntent()
```

Comment: Can you write a full code like in the notification class we can implement? it would be more understandable for others as well